# meet strange during build up the basic 2D grids for future simulation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, 2d

I am doing one project while stuck at the first step. The idea is to set up a 3D model. The (x,y) is the geometry area and z is the value of interests. I need simulate all area of (x,y) coordinates.Firstly, I try to initiate the z value for all (x,y) coordinate. I met problems at this step by following codes.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // use the rectangle as the "unit" of the 2D model.

    var x = [];
    var y = [];
    var z = [];
    var R1 = 5;

    var dataset = [];

    // use function to initiate a row       
    var rowGen = function(k){
        for (j=0;j<10;j++){            
        x.push(j*5);
        y.push(k*2);       
        z.push(R1);
        dataset.push({x:x[j],y:y[j],z:z[j]});
        }          
    }           
    // initiate 10 rows
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        rowGen(i);
        }
```

This always just initiate the z value for parts of the (x,y) area. Just the first row (y=0). I checked dataset in console, it has the correct numbers(100) of objects （x,y,z）, while all of them have y=0, which shows in the figure only one line, instead of 2D area.
I tried a different loops to do that but just can not find out the solution. Could you please help bring me some light?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the logic bug. I had pushed the wrong value into y.Changed the code as below works.

```
        // use the rectangle as the "unit" of the 2D model.

        var x = [];
        var y = [];
        var z = [];
        var R1 = 5;

        var dataset = [];

       // use function to initiate a row       
       var rowGen = function(k){
       for (j=0;j<10;j++){            
        x.push(j*5);
        y.push(k*2);       
        z.push(R1);
        dataset.push({x:x[j],y:k*2,z:z[j]});
       }          
      }           
      // initiate 10 rows
      for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            rowGen(i);
           }
```